# elasticsearch text complexity calculation

Tags: elasticsearch

My elasticsearch server indexes 1 million articles.
I would like to rank those articles according to text complexity by using something like [Lexile mesures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexile)

Does elasticsearch provide this calculations or do I need an external program to calculate this?
If it's an external program, how do I integrate the results with elasticsearch?